# [C++][DPDK] Create a rte_mempool with the correct "private size" byte alignment

Tags: c++, segmentation-fault, memory-alignment, dpdk

I'm pretty new with DPDK and working with bytes in general.

I'm trying to modify the length of a received packet by copying it in a mempool, then creating a rte_mbuf with said mempool, which i can modify.
To create the mempool i use

```
    mem_pool = rte_pktmbuf_pool_create(packet, 1,
                        RTE_MBUF_DEFAULT_DATAROOM, <?>,
                        RTE_MBUF_DEFAULT_BUF_SIZE,
                        SOCKET_ID_ANY);
```

descripted in http://dpdk.org/doc/api/rte__mbuf_8h.html#a593921f13307803b94bbb4e0932db962

I seem to get always the wrong value for the priv_size in this call as i receive this error:

```
    MBUF: mbuf priv_size=<variable> is not aligned 
    Segmentation fault
```

I can't find more information in the description and googled the problem a lot but i won't find the solution, can anyone illuminate me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [link to the documentation](http://dpdk.org/doc/api/rte__mbuf_8h.html#a593921f13307803b94bbb4e0932db962) you provided quotes:

> priv_size Size of application private are between the rte_mbuf structure and the data buffer. This value must be aligned to RTE_MBUF_PRIV_ALIGN.

So yes, the priv_size should be aligned to RTE_MBUF_PRIV_ALIGN which is 8 bytes.

So you must pass to `rte_pktmbuf_pool_create` priv_size of 0, 8, 16, 24 etc.

Comment: I simply used an uint16_t initialized to 0 and it did the trick, thank you! I guess i needed an example to understand